# Core plot: doxygen config file does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings, core-plot

I know there is an instruction for using Core Plot in my app. Do I need to configure XCode when I compile and run Core Plot examples?

```
doxygen config file does not exist
/CorePlot_1.0/Source/framework/../build/CorePlot-CocoaTouch.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Documentation.build/Script-C3566B7F10EED04900FB3866.sh: line 18: /Applications/Doxygen.app/Contents/Resources/doxygen: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build script couldn't find the Doxygen executable. Make sure it's installed in your /Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure once that you are executing project name file.

[image: You should execute your project file]